# c++ vector, ошибка при указании на последний элемент

Tags: c++, vector, итераторы

```
std::vector<std::string> addBorder(std::vector<std::string> p) {

vector<std::string>::iterator it;  
it = p.begin();  //вот тут нормально указывает
p.insert(it, "*");
p.push_back("*");
int j = p.size() - 1;     //а если здесь написать "it = p.end();
for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++)
{
    p[0].push_back('*');
    p[j].push_back('*');  //здесь "it" вместо "j",  то на этой строчке выдает 
}                         //"no match for 'operator[]'" на позиции "p[it]"
return p;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно в данном случае указать на последний элемент. Заодно и на первый, если и тут намудрил.

---

**После ответа, на память^^** :

```
std::vector<std::string> addBorder(std::vector<std::string> p) {

p.insert(p.begin(), "*");
p.push_back("*");
for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++)
{
     p.front().push_back('*'); 
     p.back().push_back('*');
}
return p;
}
```

Comment: Думаю не нужно вспоминать как  это сделать,  а нужно  изучать и  знать что к чему

Comment: совершенно верно, я оставил это в качестве пояснения тем, кто нагуглит этот вопрос)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так с использованием итераторов

```
 std::vector<std::string> addBorder(std::vector<std::string> p)
 {
    p.insert(p.begin(), "*");
    p.push_back("*");
    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator pIt = p.begin(); pIt != p.end(); pIt++ )
    {
        pIt->insert(pIt->begin(), '*');
        pIt->push_back('*');
    }

    return p;
 }
```

для вектора содержащего  `"str1", "str2"` результатом будет `"***","*str1*", "*str2*","***"`

Этот код не будет работать должным образом:

```
std::vector<std::string> addBorder(std::vector<std::string> p)
{
    p.insert(p.begin(), "*");
    p.push_back("*");
    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++)
    {
         p.front().push_back('*'); //Здесь обращение только к первой 
         p.back().push_back('*'); //и последней строке
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Да это и нужно было в итоге, пытался сам доделать. У меня там второй цикл для добавления звезд в конец строк и в начало. В конец вставляет символ, а в начало никак не хочет, все перепробовал.   Только собирался еще вопрос задать, а вы тут уже ответили, спасибо) Осталось только понять, что есть все это)))

Answer (score 0):

Обращение к элементу по индексу `std::vector::operator[]( size_type pos )` принимает
аргументом индекс типа `size_t`, вы же пытаетесь вместо индекса использовать итератор. 
Вам нужен доступ к последнему элементу вектора. Используйте `p.back()` для этого. Для доступа к первому элементу используйте `p.front()`

Comment: я пробовал, тогда выдает ошибку на строке `it = p.back()`

Comment: @NoserdanAtoms а вам принципиально работать с итераторами? Почему бы не сделать так:  for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++)
{
    p.front().push_back('*');
    p.back().push_back('*'); 
}

Comment: Принципиально сделать так, как проще) Спасибо огромное.